# Outlook 2010 spacing issue between tables rows

Tags: html, html-table, html-email, outlook-2010

I have a single table HTML with 3 columns (25px : 580px : 25px) with white background throughout table, trs and tds. All works in every browser except Outlook 2010.

In Outlook 2010 I am receiving vertical gaps in the two outer columns between table rows - its about a 3px gap. It appears the background white is either not displaying throughout the cell or Outlook is adding in a line break or similar.

Screenshot here:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/ft3zqg7jl/]

The structure of the affected rows is as:

```
<tr><td height="20" width="25" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
<td height="20" width="580" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
<td height="20" width="25" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
</tr>
```

Anyone any ideas what causes this and how to resolve?

Comment: Try `border-collapse: collapse;`

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Set `background-color: #ffffff` with CSS
2. Add a `&nbsp;` in the affected `td`s and use CSS to set `font-size: 0px` and `line-height: 0px`
3. Try both of the above *at the same time* :)

Answer (score 0):

Images should be set to inline display:block

Add into your embedded CSS:

```
table, table td { border:0; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0; padding:0; }`
```

You should put your bgcolors in the  tag instead of table-cells:

```
<table bgcolor="#ededed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
  <td>
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td height="20" width="25" align="left" valign="top"></td>
      <td height="20" width="580" align="left" valign="top"></td>
      <td height="20" width="25" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```